# new to angular2 karma testing - adding app.module to TestBed.configureTestingModule

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using angular-cli with angular2 v4.0 with angular material.

Dudes..what with all of the errors?  I am trying to learn karma and if I run npm tests I get 34 fails all related to material.. e.g.

```
Can't bind to 'routerLinkActive' since it isn't a known property of 'a'
Can't bind to 'md-menu-trigger-for' since it isn't a known property of 'button'
Can't bind to 'md-menu-trigger-for' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

If 'md-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

On and on

How to I make angular material play nice with karma?

My app works fine but if up to karma..would be a total disaster.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have a LOT! of declarations, entryComponents, imports, and providers in my @NgModule n  the app.module.ts file.  It appears I have to add each one in e.g. my dashboard.component.spec.ts file.  I am adding one by one and is not getting stupid.  I really dont want to add unrelated components.  How can I just import  the app.module.ts file?  I have 50 more to import...

This is they type of error I am getting:

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component BlankComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

If I import then great..error will go away only to complain about another..

How do I streamline?

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { MaterialModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { LoggedinService } from '../loggedin.service';
import { BusyService } from '../busy.service';
import { DbBusyService } from '../dbbusy.service';


import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ROUTES } from '../app.routes';

import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { CallbackComponent } from '../callback/callback.component';


describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent,
                      LoginComponent,
                      CallbackComponent],
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
      ],
      providers: [
        LoggedinService,
        BusyService,
        DbBusyService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I thins tried this but I got the below error.  So I assume there is a way o import app.module and add to TestBed.configureTestingModule but not clear how to do it.

```
import { AppModule } from '../app.module';
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent,
                      LoginComponent,
                      CallbackComponent],
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true }),
         AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
        LoggedinService,
        BusyService,
        DbBusyService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Failed: Type DashboardComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving DashboardComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DashboardComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.

Comment: Please show us the tests. You likely need to import (in both the ES6 and `Testbed.configureTestingModule` sense) `RouterTestingModule` from `@angular/router/testing`, and also include `MdMenuComponent` or something in the configuration.

Comment: see my edits where I added more info

Comment: I am seeing something similar on Rangle.IO.  https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/intro-to-tdd/setup/testbed-configuration.html.  I am wondering if you got though problem?  I am trying to simplify things with appmodule and getting errors myself.

Comment: Are you barreling by chance? or are all of your components declared in your app.module?

Answer (score 0):

So I had this exact same issue and I found it very frustrating that this post did not have an answer. I finally got my tests function so I am going to submit an answer that shows what resolved this issue for me. 
This has been an issue for my team for several angular releases now but we hadn't been relying on testing so this was pushed to the bottom of our fix it list.

First off I think part of this had to do with Barreling. Not all of our main components were added as declarations in the app.modules.ts file. So to start I added all the component files that had corresponding .spec files as declarations in my app.module.ts

Adding the components that had spec files to my app.module fixed the errors I had like the following:

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component BlankComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

This did not solve all of my problems however, I ended up with the following error:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[ChildrenOutletContexts]:
>   StaticInjectorError[ChildrenOutletContexts]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!

This was resolved by something mentioned on the comments for this question:

> You likely need to import (in both the ES6 and Testbed.configureTestingModule sense) RouterTestingModule from @angular/router/testing

I changed my boilerplate spec to use the RouterTestingModule, which resolved the No Provider error.

Here is what my new spec file looks like (which passes woot!):

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
   it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

So now in the declarations portion of my spec I have only the component I want to test, and for imports (boilerplate) I now have the RouterTestingModule.